# Weird behavior of boolean difference when a carving a logo in solid body

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Hi guys and thanks in advance.
I'm trying to carve a logo imported from .svg file(black) into a shape(highligthed).
Previous steps with logo are:

1. Convert to Mesh
2. Solidify

[image: #1]

After applying a boolean difference modifier, everything looks fine except 2 pieces which don't doesn't seem to have a mesh, and look odd on a render, as if the main object is hollow in this area and you can see its internals.
Seems that .svg curves are somehow broken there, but i can hardly understand what's the issue.
[image: #2]
[image: #3]

Comment: have you tried shift+n in edit mode recalculate normals?

Comment: @dave44 tried for both objects which are already solidified. Doesn't help